# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32print

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, dll, pyinstaller

I have the following code

```
from win32 import win32print

for p in win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, None, 1):
            _, _, name, _ = p
            print (name)
```

The code works.
I'm trying to create an exe file from it as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\xralf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
pyinstaller.exe --onefile C:\Users\xralf\Desktop\enumprinters.py
cd dist
enumprinters.exe
```

It writes the following error message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32print: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways I know maybe can solve your problem:

1. Update your `pyinstaller`.
2. Update your `pywin32`.
3. Try to find what's the dll it needed.(In /build/name/warnname.txt).And use `pyinstaller --add-binary 'the_path_of_dll:.' myscript.py`
4. If you are using `python 3.8`,Please use the old version.I heard that `pyinstaller` worked not very well in `python 3.8`.

Comment: Step 1 & 2 did it for me. Thanks